Inverse Galois problem for G with a derived sequence of length 2
For a finite group G with a derived sequence of length 2, please tell me how to specifically construct a field that is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and whose Galois group is G.
I made some edits to the content
(1)  For the Galois inverse problem for finite Abelian groups, the method of constructing the desired field is already known (following Dirichlet's arithmetic theorem, the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups, and the promotion theorem for Galois extensions).
(2)  As a next step, rather than immediately considering all solvable groups, I thought I would start with solvable groups whose derived sequence length is 2 (such as $\mathfrak{S}_{3}$).
(3)  Given the derived sequence $G$=$G^{(0)}$$\triangleright$$G^{(1)}$$\triangleright$$G^{(2)}$=1 as input data , I would like to construct an algorithm that outputs a simple extension $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$) of $\mathbb{Q}$ as output data ($\alpha$$\in$$\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$), or an irreducible polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the minimal factorization field over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$).

Is there any particular reason? Curious to know the application.

@David Roberts Thank you for your comment. I have just added my current knowledge and some information. In particular, I would like to know whether this problem can be solved by following the method used in the case where G is an Abelian group, or a fundamentally different method is required.
